# Capturar fecha local

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo este campo en un formulario que obtiene la hora como ven esta en **disabled**
por que no se puede modificar tiene que agregar la hora local del pc, guarda todo correcto pero siempre me guarda la hora con las  12:00 y necesito guardar la hora en que guarde los datos es decir si guarde a las 8:30 tiene que guardar en bd 8:30 y imprimir 8:30 pero siempre pone las  12 como obtengo la hora local de mi pc ?

e intentado con `$hora = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/bogota'));` pero no funciona

**Código de campo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Vista de campo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Lo que imprime al guardar**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código para insertar datos**

```
include "../config/config.php";//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
        $codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
        $title = $_POST["title"];
        $description = $_POST["description"];
        $category_id = $_POST["category_id"];
        $project_id = $_POST["project_id"];
        $realiza_id = $_POST["realiza_id"];
        $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
        $status_id = $_POST["status_id"];
        $hinicio=date("h:i:s");
        $hfin=$_POST["hfin"];
        $created_at="NOW()";




        // $user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];

    $sql="insert into actividad (codigo,title,description,hinicio,hfin,tiempo,project_id,realiza_id,user_id,status_id,created_at)
 values (\"$codigo\",\"$title\",\"$description\",\"$hinicio\",\"$hfin\",\"$tiempo\",\"$project_id\",$user_id,$status_id,$realiza_id,$created_at)";
```

**Código que imprime datos de la bd y arma la tabla**

```
 <table class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="headings">
                        <th title="Codigo de la tarea" class="column-title">Codigo</th>
                         <th title="Nombre de la tarea" class="column-title">Tarea</th>
                          <th title="Nombre de la actividad" class="column-title">Actividad</th>
                           <th title="Quien realiza la actividad" class="column-title">Realiza</th>
                            <th  class="column-title">Estado</th>
                             <th>Fecha</th>
                              <th title="Hora Inicio Actividad" class="column-title">H Inicio</th>
                               <th title="Hora Inicio Actividad" class="column-title">H Fin</th>
                                <th title="Hora Inicio Actividad" class="column-title">Tiempo</th>
                                 <th class="column-title no-link last"><span class="nobr"></span></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                 <?php 
                while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                            $id=$r['id'];
                             $codigo=$r['codigo'];
                              $title=$r['title'];
                               $project_id=$r['project_id'];
                                $realiza_id=$r['realiza_id'];
                                 $status_id=$r['status_id'];
                                  $hinicio=date('h:i', strtotime($r['hinicio']));
                                   $hfin=date('h:i', strtotime($r['hfin']));
                                    $created_at=date('d/m/Y', strtotime($r['created_at']));
                                     $description=$r['description'];
                                      $tiempo=date('h:i', strtotime($r['tiempo']));
                                       $category_id=$r['category_id'];

                            $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from tareas where id=$project_id");
                            if($c=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                $name_project=$c['name'];
                            }


                            $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from realiza where id=$realiza_id");
                            if($c=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                $name_realiza=$c['name'];
                            }


                            $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from status where id=$status_id");
                            if($c=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                $name_status=$c['name'];
                            }


                ?>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>" id="id<?php echo $id;?>">
                     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $codigo;?>" id="codigo<?php echo $id;?>">
                      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $title;?>" id="title<?php echo $id;?>">
                       <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $tiempo;?>" id="tiempo<?php echo $id;?>">
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $hinicio;?>" id="hinicio<?php echo $id;?>">
                         <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $hfin;?>" id="hfin<?php echo $id;?>">
                          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $description;?>" id="description<?php echo $id;?>">
                    <!-- me obtiene los datos -->
                     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $project_id;?>" id="project_id<?php echo $id;?>">
                      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $realiza_id;?>" id="realiza_id<?php echo $id;?>">
                       <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $category_id;?>" id="category_id<?php echo $id;?>">
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $status_id;?>" id="status_id<?php echo $id;?>">

                    <tr class="even pointer">
                        <td><?php echo $codigo;?></td>
                         <td><?php echo $name_project; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $title;?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $name_realiza;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $name_status;?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $created_at;?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $hinicio;?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $hfin;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $tiempo;?></td>
```

Comment: ¿ Quieres capturar **la hora local del cliente** o **la hora local del servidor** ? No tienen porqué coincidir.

Comment: del cliente osea de la maquina en el que el usuario este entrando a la app

Answer (score 1):

Para guardar únicamente la hora basta con que lo realices de la siguiente manera:

Formato de 12 Horas:

```
$hora = date('h:i');
```

Formato de 24 Horas:

```
$hora = date('H:i');
```

Esto solo para guardar la hora con sus minutos, ya que puedes agregar más parámetros para que te dé la hora a tu gusto.

Para más información puedes visitar la página de [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com) y ver la función [date()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp).

Esto toma la hora del servidor, por lo tanto, si quieres definir una zona horaria puedes hacerlo agregando esta línea a tu archivo:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota");
```

Comment: Este código sería en la parte del servidor, correcto?

Comment: Así es, puedes asignarle ese valor a la variable y guardar el registro, cuando lo jales para mostrarlo saldrá ese valor guardado. Lo curioso es que tu muestras en tu código que estas utilizando un input type time y en donde muestras la vista del campo se muestra un type date.

Comment: Si ya voy a revisar muchas gracias @EduardoJavierMaldonado

Comment: La solución fue mas sencilla, solo puse esto dentro del código date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota");  gracias

Comment: @EstebanGiraldo si es exactamente lo que yo te puse, aunque no se porque tienes marcada como respuesta la otra. Vi que la has cambiado varias veces.

Answer (score 1):

La manera más fácil de hacerlo es configurar el campo ena base de datos como "timestamp" de esa manera en ese campo se guardará la fecha y hora en la cual realizaste la inserción.

Solo recuerda no mandar ningún valor a ese campo cuando el hagas el query insert

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres hacerlo del lado del cliente debes hacerlo con javascript porque el se ejecuta en el cliente:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td id="mi_td">erg</td>
    </tr>
</table>

     <?php
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        var d = new Date(),
        h = (d.getHours()<10?"0":"") + d.getHours(),
        m = (d.getMinutes()<10?"0":"") + d.getMinutes();
         document.getElementById("mi_td").innerHTML =h + ":" + m)
        </script>'; 
?>
```

Aunque creo que lo ideal es agarrar la hora del servidor, ya que la maquina del cliente puede estar desfasada

```
 $time = date('h:i');
```

Para ellos debes configurar tu php.ini :

```
 date.timezone=America/El_Salvador
```

Comment: La solución fue mas sencilla, solo puse esto dentro del código date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota"); gracias

Answer (score -2):

intentalo de esta manera

```
    $id=$r['id'];
                     $codigo=$r['codigo'];
                      $title=$r['title'];
                       $project_id=$r['project_id'];
                        $realiza_id=$r['realiza_id'];
                         $status_id=$r['status_id'];
                          $hinicio=date('G:i:s', strtotime($r['hinicio']));
                           $hfin=date('G:i:s', strtotime($r['hfin']));
                            $created_at=date('d/m/Y', strtotime($r['created_at']));
                             $description=$r['description'];
                              $tiempo=$hfin - $hinicio;
                               $category_id=$r['category_id'];
```